# Write to location access violation, variable shared between threads

Tags: c#, selenium, unity-game-engine, selenium-chromedriver

I'm building an Unity application that makes some use of Selenium webdriver, I start the headless browser(chromedriver) in another Thread. In that thread I keep taking screenshots of what is shown in the headless browser, and store it in an byte array.
In the main thread I have to use that byte array to make an image that Unity understands(Texture2D).
I start the application, it works for a little while, but after some time has passed the application crashes. The crash file says:

> UnityPlayer.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005) in module
> UnityPlayer.dll at 0023:105311be.
>
> Error occurred at 2020-07-30_150418.
> C:\Codes\Apps\MyApp\MyApp.exe, run by Fabio.
>
> 94% memory in use.
>
> 0 MB physical memory [423 MB free].
>
> 0 MB paging file [1990 MB free].
>
> 0 MB user address space [108 MB free].
>
> Write to location 007e7200 caused an access violation.

second thread and the method "LoadImage"(as Coroutine) are started as soon as the application starts()

code that take the screenshot:

```
public async Task ScreenShotBrowser()
    {
        //await Task.Yield();
        while (isBrowserOpen)
        {
                Screenshot screenshot = ssdriver.GetScreenshot();  //Selenium stuff
            lock (imgArray)
            {
                imgArray = screenshot.AsByteArray;               
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        
    }
```

loads the image to into the unity material:

```
IEnumerator LoadImage()
    {
        while (!isBrowserOpen) { yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.1f); } // ugly code, but avoid freezing

        while (isBrowserOpen)
        {
            
            lock (imgArray)
            {
                mat.mainTexture = loadTexture(imgArray);
            }
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.1f); 
        }
    }

    private Texture2D loadTexture(byte[] imageArray)
    {
            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        lock (imageArray)
        {
            tex.LoadImage(imageArray);
        }
        return tex;
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Setting the `lock` variable to a new reference inside the `lock`, as you do in `ScreenShotBrowser()`, seems like it could be...problematic.  I _think_ you might be ok here since you're not doing anything more inside that `lock` after setting a new reference, but the amount of thinking required to determine if that is, indeed, safe might be best avoided by just creating a dedicated, `readonly` field to `lock` on.

Comment: @BACON I feel like this would be ok since afaik you set the `lock` on the `imageArray` reference address .. not the referenced object itself (might be completely wrong though). But yeah just to be really sure you should simply use the recommended `private readonly object lockObject = new object();`

Comment: @derHugo The lock is for the referenced object, not the reference itself; otherwise `private readonly object lockObject = null;` would be sufficient. Also, under the covers a `lock` statement copies the provided reference to a hidden variable, I believe so it can still exit the lock even if the reference changes thereafter. Here, if `ScreenShotBrowser()` continued using `imgArray` inside the `lock` I believe that new array wouldn't be "protected" because it `lock`ed on the _old_ array. I don't think that `lock` usage is necessary, anyways, because setting a reference is an atomic operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this is the issue but I think what happens here is that you indeed run out of memory.

```
private Texture2D loadTexture(byte[] imageArray)
{
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    lock (imageArray)
    {
        tex.LoadImage(imageArray);
    }
    return tex;
}
```

This creates and loads a new `Texture2D` all the time quite often in your app. But even if the texture is not referenced anymore it is **not** automatically GC collected! You have to actively destroy it.

So I would either do something like

```
IEnumerator LoadImage()
{
    // You could also use this
    yield return new WaitWhile(()=>!isBrowserOpen);

    while (isBrowserOpen)
    {
        // destroy the current texture first
        if(mat.mainTexture) Destroy(mat.mainTexture);

        lock (imgArray)
        {
            mat.mainTexture = loadTexture(imgArray);
        }

        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.1f); 
    }
}
```

or alternatively not even create a new texture everytime but rather simply do

```
private Texture2D loadTexture(byte[] imageArray, Texture2D tex)
{
    lock (imageArray)
    { 
        // Load into and overwrite the existing texture
        tex.LoadImage(imageArray);
    }
}

IEnumerator LoadImage()
{
    // You could also use this
    yield return new WaitWhile(()=>!isBrowserOpen);

    // Create the texture once if it doesn't exist yet
    if(!mat.mainTexture) mat.mainTexture = new Texture2D(1f, 1f);

    while (isBrowserOpen)
    {
        lock (imgArray)
        {
            loadTexture(imgArray, mat.mainTexture);
        }

        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.1f); 
    }
}
```

---

In addition to that like mentioned in the comments it might be an issue to `lock` the `imgArray` but then exchange that reference later in `imgArray = screenshot.AsByteArray;`. Here I'm not sure but just to be save you should follow the recommendations of using a dedicated object just for the lock like

```
///<summary>
/// This is the Lock object for <see cref="imgArray" />
/// </summary>
private readonly object imgArrayLock = new object();

private Texture2D loadTexture(byte[] imageArray, Texture2D tex)
{
    lock (imgArrayLock)
    { 
        // Load into and overwrite the existing texture
        tex.LoadImage(imageArray);
    }
}

IEnumerator LoadImage()
{
    // You could also use this
    yield return new WaitWhile(()=>!isBrowserOpen);

    // Create the texture once if it doesn't exist yet
    if(!mat.mainTexture) mat.mainTexture = new Texture2D(1f, 1f);

    while (isBrowserOpen)
    {
        lock (imgArrayLock)
        {
            loadTexture(imgArray, mat.mainTexture);
        }

        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.1f); 
    }
}
```

Comment: So, its up and running for something around 1hour and a half. I did take out the ' new texture2d(1,1)' from the method, and just create it in Start() once. Tho, in previous try outs I put an int counter in Update so around every 80 calls, I call GC,Collect(). This still crashed the game.